# Why do Italians respond to 'grazie' with 'di niente'?

Tags: grammar

Why do Italians respond to 'grazie' with 'di niente'?

Comment: @I.M., mi sa che sono scomparsi i commenti che c'erano precedentemente qui...

Comment: @DaG The timeline tells that there was only one comment, and it didn't disappear - it was simply moved below to Gabriele's answer.

Comment: Thanks, @I.M. I believed there were more comments here, among which the first one to mention *Keine Ursache* (before Gabriele's answer). I might mix it up with some other question.

Answer (score 31):

Because it means

> You have nothing to thank me about

which is somehow equivalent to the English expressions

> Don't mention it
>   Not at all
>   No worries

and [so on](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42697/different-ways-to-say-youre-welcome).

The idea is minimizing the importance of what the person is thanking you for, letting her understand it wasn't a hassle for you, therefore resulting in a polite expression.

Other alternative forms

> Di nulla
>   Non c'è di che

the latter literally expressing the concept *Non c'è di che ringraziarmi*

---

Spanish and Portuguese, as well as French, do the same

> De nada

and

> De rien

As suggested by I.M. in the comments this is also true in German

> Keine Ursache

and Swedish

> ingen orsak

and Danish

> ingen årsag

Comment: Nice to know! Noted ;)

Comment: How about adding "You are welcome" to the proposed list of English expressions?

Comment: It's made on purpose, as it literally doesn't mean the same thing. All the expressions I listed have in common the negative form, explicitly used to minimize the act itself.

Comment: Besides "di nulla", also "non c'è di che", which should be the most clear of them all.

Comment: @I.M.: also "nichts zu danken" in German, which in Italian would be "niente di cui ringraziare"

Comment: Yes, such response is also very common in Slovene where, after being thanked, one usually answers with "Ni zakaj", which is equivalent to "Di niente".

Comment: Italians (me too) often also answer with "Figùrati", but actually I miss where it comes from :)

Comment: You dont say "Keine Ursache" in German. NO NO. - Nichts dafür - Gern geschehen
- Bitte , etc..

Comment: @cristian "keine Ursache" is perfectly fine. Just because it's not used whereever you are doesn't mean it's wrong (I never knew "da nicht für", for example, before I talked to people from Westfalen).

Comment: In Danish also "det var så lidt" (it was so little), ie. almost nothing, similar to di niente.

Answer (score 8):

It's an equivalent of "Not at all" in British English and "No problem" in American English, used just as a *polite but informal* reply after someone has thanked you.